# Check if default export of a file is a React function component or a regular function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, bun

I'm trying to determine which modules export React function components vs. regular functions. Bun uses file-based routing, so I can match the request to determine which module file to dynamically import based on the request pathname.

Let's say I have 2 files:

`react-route.tsx`:

```
export default () => {
    return <h1>hello, world</h1>
}
```

`api-route.ts`:

```
export default () => {
    return Response.json({ hello: 'world' })
}
```

I import the module like so in my Bun server:

```
const router = new Bun.FileSystemRouter({
    style: 'nextjs',
    dir: './app/routes',
})

const match = router.match(req)

if (!match) {
    return new Response('404')
}

const route = await import(match.filePath)

// is route.default a react function component or a regular function?
```

If `route.default` in the example above is a React function, then I want to call `renderToString(<route.default />)` and use that for the Bun response. Otherwise, I want to just call `route.default()` since it's a normal function.

I've tried using React's `isValidElement` but it always returns false. I'm guessing because I'd have to wrap it in a tag first, but if it isn't an actual React function, that will cause problems.

What is the best way to determine if the module's default export function is a React function or just a regular function?

Comment: You can't know what a function returns without calling it - it's easy to write one like `() => condition ? <p>Hi<p> : Response.json({ message: "Hi" })` that could return _either_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so the only way to do this is check the return type of the function and see if it's type is a JSX.Element?

Comment: Functions don't _have_ return types at runtime; TypeScript metadata is erased in transpilation to JavaScript.

Comment: React components don't have return JSX. Returning a JSON string is also perfectly valid as far as React is concerned, so from that perspective both of your functions can be React components.

Comment: @Etheryte  in that case i guess the only way is to check the file extension, and if it's`.tsx` then assume its a react function? because i have no clue how to do this otherwise

Comment: Just add 2 routers, one prefixed with `/api` and if that's the case, it's an api.

Comment: @jdion84 - Even then, there's no rule that says the default export of a `.tsx` file has to be a component. Nor is there any rule that components must use JSX. You'll need some way of signalling what the module is for alongside / separate from its default export. Where it is, a filename convention more restrictive than just `.tsx` or not, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not be able to determine the return type of the function at runtime without calling it.

You could attach [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)s to the routes to be able to determine the type?

```
const PAGE_ROUTE = Symbol('PAGE_ROUTE');

type PageFn<T extends unknown> = T & { __routeType: typeof PAGE_ROUTE };

function pageRoute<T extends unknown>(fn: T): PageFn<T> {
    const pageFn = fn as PageFn<T>;

    pageFn.__routeType = PAGE_ROUTE;

    return pageFn;
}

const API_ROUTE = Symbol('API_ROUTE');

type ApiFn<T extends unknown> = T & { __routeType: typeof API_ROUTE };

function apiRoute<T extends unknown>(fn: T): ApiFn<T> {
    const apiFn = fn as ApiFn<T>;

    apiFn.__routeType = API_ROUTE;

    return apiFn;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

const page = pageRoute(() => null);

const api = apiRoute(() => null);

[page, api].forEach((fn) => {
    if (fn.__routeType === PAGE_ROUTE) {
        console.log('Page route');
    } else if (fn.__routeType === API_ROUTE) {
        console.log('API route');
    }
});
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&q=170#code/MYewdgzgLgBACgQQOIFED6AlA8gVQCoowC8MAygJ4C2ARiADYAUA5IqprgUwJQDcAUHyjkADgFN4AQwDmogGJgAPHhiiAHlFFgAJhBgBXMAGswIAO5gAfMRjKAZDADeMNGgBOIPRrwjRALhhCYiAAZvDI6Nj4hAC+-HzBBsBQAJbgMMLSohgeGkoq6po6+kYm5hYMwWD+eFz+cJnySlYOfDBtMKCQsBky8taVMBK69b2KeBZx7ekNYAB0Lu6eot5i1qwRHCiT7a6iUHquYNOj-NECndAwCHAAkuxR1hQ09MzXd5GcvAKB4gjCyY1lGoNNpdAZjGZLNY7I5nG4cssfP4fiErrd7gQYLEBAkwElUkcJP9sks8sDCmCSpDypVqrUrv9Ac1Wu0LrAiQCjiQBkMGZymts2hz5PN4UsVuISG8MVsBFNdvtDoNGWBTgIAPQAKhgAFo9fqDYajcaTaazeaLZb9TBNerzuBLj1JccsgiGAwuMQrGA9HQ6F8+GzlclrBySRp3Z6iN7ff64gBtJ0AGmDAF1ZsEQK4UBJgAALd2VKPMqbJUIVOYLBES4hEEjrGWelpTKYXeiiWZ0EBSZgjcSLDTcfhTaIqOgQcRlmAV0UDxGrOtS9EfFBNlktjoO9ud7uvW4wOdD9dYvjRXhAA).